# how to calculate the mean value of pixels of a raster in Grass plugin in qgis?

Tags: grass-gis, raster-calculator

I am using grass plugin in qgis 2.12. I have to estimate the average value of all the pixels but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you know how to handle your Mapset and populate it with raster maps, you can use a combination of **r.sum** and **r.report** modules.

After Open your Mapset with the GRASS Tool, at the Statistics section of **r.modules** (filtered them with r.), you can observe both (see next image).

[image]

At the next image, you can see the output of **r.sum** for my particular raster dem. The value was 2424831264.000000.

[image]

Next result was obtained with **r.report** module and the "Cell counts" option. Its value was 1328880 (my raster has not NULL values). So, the average value of all pixels is 2424831264/1328880 = 1824.71800614.

[image]

For automating this process you have to use **grass.script** python module.